# How to deal with namespaces in XML with Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rspec, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I have this XML document:

```
<item>
  <title>The Big Bang Theory - Temporada 1</title>
  <lge:titleid>season_id4</lge:titleid>
  <lge:thumb>https://d12h56qju7t1ah.cloudfront.net/system/artworks/4/h80/the-big-bang-theory-1.20130326114106.jpg?1364298066</lge:thumb>
</item>
```

and parse it with:

```
parsed = Nokogiri::XML.parse(File.read(file_doc))
```

`parsed.class` returns "Nokogiri::XML::Document".

But when I do:

```
parsed.at_xpath('lge:titleid').text
```

I get:

```
Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Undefined namespace prefix: //lge:titleid
```

What could be the reason for this and how can I get the text of that particular node?

Comment: You should define namespace, something like `parsed.at_xpath('lge:titleid', 'lge' => 'http://lge.com/')`. And somewhere in your doc should be tag with namespace, for example ` <item xmlns="http://lge.com/">`. Read more there: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html

Comment: Yes.. you are very right. But in this case I am getting XML Feed from other source like this without defining namespace in root element. So this is an exceptional case. So in this scenario how can I get it..

Comment: Well, try `parsed.remove_namespaces!` to remove all namespaces and search like this: `parsed.at_xpath('titleid').text`.

Comment: The issue is that in my code after parsing it returns as Nokogiri::XML:Element class. So in the code parsed.at_xpath('lge:episode').text works fine.. But when I am writing specs for it, after parsing it returns as Nokogiri::XML::Document class and hence parsed.at_xpath('lge:episode') wont work.

Comment: So is there any way to convert Nokogiri::XML:Element to Nokogiri::XML::Document for vice versa.. I think if that is possible then it would work fin